# React state hooks are calling the initial state whenever the page is rerendered and not sure why

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I’m having an issue where whenever one of my React components re-renders on a page, all of the state hooks call their initial states (which are functions that return data).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsPpY.png)

For example, in the code snippet above when I call `setTroughLetters()` upon the press of a button in this component, `createNewTileBag()`, `tileBag.takeRandomTiles(7)`, and `createNewBoard()` all get called again. I tried to circumvent this problem by doing something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUwag.png)

And making the initial states empty. However, props in this component which rely on the initial states are throwing errors because I imagine that `useEffect` occurs after the fact.

I also tried something like this which I intended to check for the existence of the tile bag then call `createNewTileBag()` only if it didn’t exist yet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9328.png)

To my unfortunate realization though, `tileBag` needs to be initialized before you can test if it contains any data.

Is there any way to solve this problem that I’m having?

Comment: instead of something like `useState(createNewTileBag())` do `useState(() => createNewTileBag())`.

Comment: Please put actual code in your question, not images of code I have to click on a link to see.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix this issue by providing `useState` a function that returns the initial value you wish to use such as `useState(() => createNewTileBag())`.

A brief explanation is below:

```
// This is an example function that will wait (roughly) X seconds before returning the value 1
// This will help to illistrate the differences in the two methods.
const expensiveTask = (seconds) => {
    var start = new Date();

    while((new Date() - start) / 1000 < seconds);

    return 1;
}

// This example shows how using a command such as useState(expensiveTask(5)) is processed each render
// The useState code has been split into two lines to improve clarity.
const Example1Component = () => {
    // The expensive value is processed.
    // This expensive value will be processed every render.
    const initialExpensiveValue = expensiveTask(5);

    // The expensive value is passed to the useState to use as the inital value.
    // The expensive value will only be inserted into the state on component mount,
    // on all other renders it is ignored.
    const [expensiveValue, setExpensiveValue] = useState(initialExpensiveValue);

    return (
        <div>
            {expensiveValue}
        </div>
    )
}

// This example shows how using a command such as useState(() => expensiveTask(5)) is processed each render
// The useState code has been split into two lines to improve clarity.
const Example2Component = () => {
    // The function is created (not run).
    // This function will be created on each render.
    // Function creation performace impact in most situations can be considered insignificant.
    const initialExpensiveValueFn = () => expensiveTask(5);

    // The function is passed to the useState and will be run to get the inital value.
    // The function will only be run on component mount, on all other renders it is only created.
    const [expensiveValue, setExpensiveValue] = useState(initialExpensiveValueFn);

    return (
        <div>
            {expensiveValue}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that helps so much and makes things clear